# How to print native C log inside JNI-C code?

Tags: c, java-native-interface, jnienv

I have the following JNI C code

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_XYZ_addData
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject callingObject, jlong sensorId)
{

  int status =
    getSensorMeasurement ((void *) sensorId);
    printf ("status_code %d  \n", status);
}
```

I have bunch of log messages inside getSensorMeasurement(..) C code

When I invoke the JNI-C code from Java code;

- it only prints status_code
- but the log messages inside getSensorMeasurement(..) are not printed in console.

How can I get hold of the console logs from internal C code ?

Thanks
Kaniska

Comment: The logs should be written to the console, exactly as you see the status log. So the question is - what is the code that tries to write to the log inside getSensorMeasurement? Something is probably wrong there, more details are required here.

Comment: Can you share the code that generates logs inside getSensorMeasurement function?